# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error when start solr

Tags: java, jvm, solr, tomcat6, lucene

I start indexing DB articles with solr, but after add about 58 million article (and about 113 GB size of disk) , i get below error message on tomcat log error

Note1: i already set Init memory pool  to 256MB, and Max memory pool:1400MB to tomcat server. 
Note2: I can post or search article but must wait over 3 min for get response.

```
8-apr-2010 14:27:07 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.initialize(PriorityQueue.java:89)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.HitQueue.<init>(HitQueue.java:67)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector.<init>(TopScoreDocCollector.java:113)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector.<init>(TopScoreDocCollector.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector$InOrderTopScoreDocCollector.<init>(TopScoreDocCollector.java:42)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector$InOrderTopScoreDocCollector.<init>(TopScoreDocCollector.java:40)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector.create(TopScoreDocCollector.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:979)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:884)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:341)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:182)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:195)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:574)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's problem ?

Have any suggestion ?

**Important Question: Why solr using heap memory ???**

Comment: Have you tried to attach jconsole to get a better look what is going on?

Comment: Is it ok for the memory footprint to increase? are you storing some part of the index in memory? If the answer is no, I suppose this is a memory leak. Try using: jmap -histo <process id> to see what kind of objects occupy a larger portion of the heap than expected.

Comment: thanks for reply. i don't know many about java, also i can'f find jmap. only install YourKit java profiler on server. how to find what's problem ?

Comment: what are you using to index your documents? DataImportHandler?

Comment: 256 to 1,4 gig mb is anyways not very much for a Solr

Comment: Mauricio, I using XmlImportHandler by method from .net, also i already converted 87 million article and move to other solr server with not any problem (i have totaly 170 million article till now). i don't know why get this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Upgrade to the latest jdk 6 if you haven't already. I hit a similar OOME on jdk 5 that went away with 6. I suspect an nio thing.
2. Try lowering maxPendingDeletes in your solrconfig.xml.
3. To find out what component of solr is using up all of the memory, start solr like this:

   java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=some_directory_of_your_choice -jar start.jar

Then parse the heap dump using the stand-alone MAT from http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ and lower the corresponding cache that is eating up all your memory.

Comment: I just install windows 64 bit for set bigger memory for tomcat (solr)
and my problem solve, because segment very large and can't open with low memory.

Answer (score 1):

Enable GC logging and graph the timeseries, this can tell you velocity of JVM memory allocation and how much is being collected if at all so you can approximate a high water mark.